# How to prove in sequent calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

build output

$$(\forall x)(\exists y) y \approxeq g(x,y), (\forall x)R(x,x) \vdash (\forall x)(\exists y)R(y,g(x,y))$$

I got to this step and I don’t understand what to do next:

$$
y \approxeq g(x,y), (\forall x)R(x,x) \vdash (\exists y)R(y,g(x,y))
$$

I think i need to use this rule at the end:

$$
\frac{\Gamma \vdash t_1 \approxeq s_1 \quad \cdots \quad \Gamma \vdash t_n \approxeq s_n \quad \Gamma \vdash \left ( \varphi \right )_{t_1, \ldots, t_n}^{x_1, \ldots, x_n}}{\Gamma \vdash \left ( \varphi \right )_{s_1, \ldots, s_n}^{x_1, \ldots, x_n}}
$$

but i don't know what steps i need to take to do it

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Welcome to mse! I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't). In the future you should do the same so that other users have an easier time finding this question ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Call $\Gamma$ the set of premises.

Using rules for quantifiers we have: $\Gamma \vdash a=g(x,a)$ and $\Gamma \vdash R(a,a)$.

Then you are right; you need the following instance of the above rule:

$\dfrac { \Gamma \vdash t_1=s_1 \ \ \Gamma \vdash \varphi^{x_1}_{t_1} }{\Gamma \vdash \varphi^{x_1}_{s_1} }$

where $\varphi$ is $R(a,x_1)$.

Thus, we have: $\Gamma \vdash R(a, g(x,a))$.

The conclusion follows by $(\exists \text I)$ followed by $(\forall \text I)$.

---

If you want to prove it in Sequent Calculus, you have to start from the equality axiom and re-introduce the quantifiers.